# SDA pin on I2C lines seems weird

Tags: voltage, noise, i2c, debugging, analysis

I am trying to analyze the I2C commands sent by a PC software to [R3910 DSP chip](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/R3910-D.PDF)

The software uses a programming box (provided by the same company that manufactures the R3910 chip) to communicate with the chip via I2C. The software can send commands to do things like mute/unmute the chip, change parameters, enable disable features, etc. The chip has dedicated SCL, SDA pins and logic high on these lines is around 1.29 V, logic low is 0.

I am using the [Analog input pin of an LHT00SU1 logic analyser](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Noname_LHT00SU1) and [PulseView software](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads) to view changes on the SDA and SCL lines. The SCL line seems to show a normal pattern, consistent with what would expect an I2C command to look like. A section of the total data collected on the SCL pin when sending the mute command from the PC software is given below:

[image]

The SDA line, however, looks normal at some places and distorted at others.

[image]

The first few cycles on hte left side of this figure look ok, and what I would expect on an I2C line, but in the middle the picture looks sort of strange, for example logic low not going all the way to 0, while at the right I am not sure what is going on at all. I get this same patern on the SDA line if the repeat the experiment with a higher sampling rate for the logic analyzer. I have seen a 
similar pattern when viewing the SDA line using a high quality oscilloscope so I am thinking this is not related to the sampling frequency of my logic analyzer.

Am I getting the correct reading on the SDA/SCL lines?

The current hardware connection looks something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYhAUD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The pins from the programmer are connected directly to the I2C pads on the chip, while I hook the SCL, SDA and GND pads directly to my programmer. The actual circuit looks like this:

[image]

I have read in some blogs that I2C lines require pull up resistors, but the R3910 chip's sample schematics do not mention any pull up resistors. Plus I can control the chip using the PC flawlessly (so the I2C signal itself is not damaged) and the data in the SCL line looks normal as well, so I am assuming the chip has internal pull ups for the I2C lines. I connect the programmer with the R3910 chip on a desktop PC, while I use the logic analyzer on a separate laptop running on battery, so the logic analyzer and programmer are completely separated from each other (I read about grounding causing issues when connecting cheap logic analyzers and programmer for device under test to the same PC).

What is causing the distortion on my SDA signal and how can I make it look better on my logic analyzer?

Comment: What's the I2C clock frequency you use ..

Comment: @MituRaj I think it's around 300 kHz.

Comment: Are you using a R3910 or a R8910? Please correct the text ro schematic accordingly. If possible, provide a link to the datasheet as well.

Comment: do you have chance to reduce the frequency of operation? and also to monitor the bus voltage suing a digital multimeter when the bus is idle.

Comment: @Umar I think the I2C clock frequency is fixed, I can't find any options in the PC software to fix this. The idle pin voltages are: Vcc: 1.296 V, SDA: 1.296 V, SCL: 1.296 V

Comment: Per datasheet max SDA voltage is 1.25V, so there is something wrong with your setup already. You might need a bidirectional level shifter to operate this safely. Also your post says 1.37V, which is _way_ too much

Comment: Does the R3910DSP chip have decoupling caps?

Comment: @Huisman please see update for datasheet

Comment: @Maple do you think I need a level shifter between the programmer and chip itself? The programmer is manufactured by the chip maker and according to them they can be directly connected. But the fact the I2C idle voltages are greater than the datasheet maximum is indeed weird

Comment: @Huisman I don't think so

Comment: I think Maple is suggesting in the right direction. Regarding the decoupling caps: it (almost) never hurts adding them.

Comment: @Maple sorry the 1.37 V was a mistake, it's actually 1.29 V

Comment: @user13267 well, still too much. I'd try level shifter just to see if it helps. As for decoupling caps, in this particular case the device is very specialized. It is pretty much a SoC version of hearing aid, with only battery, mics and a switch required.

Comment: @Maple yes that's why I assumed the I2C pull ups were built in as well. Also the programmer is a standard one, manufactured by the chip makers. Could it be that the data sheet has a mistake instead? Also I can control the chip just fine, so I don't think the I2C commands themselves are damaged. Also the distortions on the graph are not random, I get the same pattern every time I issue the same command from the PC software.

Comment: Pretty sure you need pull-ups there that would reduce your voltage.

Comment: It does look like the master is much stronger to pull down than the slave. It may mean there is too strong pull-ups, but if the voltages are withing logic level specification for each chip on the bus, then it is fine. Some chips have very weak output drivers, or there might be series resistors on the slave board, so this can also be the reason for higher voltage for logic low.

Answer (score 1):

The last SCL pulse in each series belongs to the ACK bit. For addressing and write operations the SDA line is controlled by the slave during this bit time. On the right of your lower plot is read operations, where the behaviour is reversed – and now it's the 8 data bits not properly pulled down, while the host ACK bit is nice.

It seems your slave cannot properly pull down the SDA line to GND. Check the GND wiring. Especially, make sure there is no high current running through the GND line due to some short on the device board.

Don't run supply current for relays etc. through the GND line either. Use a local power supply for the external board. If you can't help the latter, use differential I²C instead.

Comment: Im not connecting relays or anything else to this circuit. The basic circuit is simply the programmer board connected to the chip (connected as specified by the manufacturer; the programmer is the standard programmer for this chip) and this much works perfectly. My only addition is i tapped in to the sda, scl and gnd connections for the logic analyzer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an Oscilloscope. The note in the logic analyser states

From the link in the question:

> The Noname LHT00SU1 is a USB-based, 8-channel logic analyzer with up
>   to 24MHz sampling rate, **with 1 additional analog channel**
>   (**theoretically 2, but only one of them can be used at a time**; 3MHz
>   analog bandwidth).

This might be the root problem. I do not suspect on the wiring as the functionality is always okay when programmed via PC

Comment: Ive tried an oscilloscope before but the overall i2c command is very long (the screenshots posted here are only a small section) and its not possible to view the whole thing in my oscilloscope. But at rare occasions when i did manage to stop the oscilloscope disply while ic2 transfer was happening, i have seen similar spikes as seen in the right side of the lower picture. Also i know about the two channel thing, i have connected the i2c line to the channel that pulseview software can display

Comment: can you disconnect the slave and then monitor the i2c line.. perhaps with only the external pull up termination? And then monitor the clock and data lines as much as possible.. i understand slave wont be there

Comment: The programmer won't work without the chip connected

Comment: can you monitor the current through the SDA line?

Comment: I don't know if I have the equipment to do that, I'd prefer alternative methods for troubleshooting this